# Generics, Interfaces and Activator

Tags: c#

I'm working on a memory caching application that can load different cache providers via configuration.  I'm doing this by defining an interface and using a plugin model to load an assembly and class that parses a file and loads a class that matches the interface.  I'd really like to define the interface and with a generic type that allows any object to be stored by the backing cache (whether that be a wrapper around third party cache client like Redis or NCache, or my own MemoryCache implementation ect.) with the ultimate goal of having a factory that I can point to a dll that wraps my caching methodology.

The issue that I am running into is errors about Generics when I use Activator to try to instantiate the plugin.  Does anyone know a way to load a class with generics to an interface?

Basic interface

```
public interface ICacheProvider<T>
{
    T Get(string key);
    bool Set(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiration);
}
```

Factory calls to load

```
public static ICacheProvider<T> GetCacheProvider(string path, string className, string configuration)
{            
    ...
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
    Type type = asm.GetType(className);

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { configuration }) as ICacheProvider<T>;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but I don't think this is good design (and I know this is not CodeReview SE).

`ICacheProvider<T>` is not very usable, because there's nothing in it that would require a separate *type* for each cacheable object. The following is, IMO, much better, plus it relieves you of `CreateInstance` headache:

```
public interface ICacheProvider
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
    bool Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiration);
}
```

Going further, I'm more than sure that concrete implementations of `ICacheProvider` work with plain `object`s, regardless of their concrete type. With this, you can further simplify your contract to:

```
public interface ICacheProvider
{
    object Get(string key);
    bool Set(string key, object value, TimeSpan expiration);
}
```

and a couple extension methods:

```
public static class CacheProviderExtensions
{
    public static T Get<T>(this ICacheProvider cacheProvider, string key);
    public static bool Set<T>(this ICacheProvider cacheProvider, string key, 
      T value, TimeSpan expiration);
}
```

Now, one of the most common operations with caches is "get-or-add" behavior, which can be expressed as yet another method on `ICacheProvider`:

```
object GetOrSet(string key, Func<object> valueProvider, TimeSpan expiration)
```

Comment: You are correct that concrete implementations work with plain objects.

 Keep in mind the sample snippets here are incredibly simplified from what they are in reality for a quick example of what I am trying to achieve.  

My intent with defining the type at initialization is to restrict a specific cache instance to a certain type.   Basically if I have say a cache of user objects, I want to limit the possibility of someone adding something else to that cache instance.  The extension methods aren't a bad idea though I feel not as error resistant as explicitly specifying the type of cache.

Comment: @anton-gogolev Why use `extension` methods when the code is actually yours ?